# AS400 DB2 IBM Connection Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, database-connection, ibm-midrange

I'm new to this topic so I wish someone could help me, I need to create a connection in C# to IBM's AS400 DB2, I really don't have much experience in this programming language and I need to create the connection for an android application in Xamarin.
Thank you

Comment: first, connecting directly from a mobile app to a db server is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.  However, if you absolutely must, you need to look at how you would generally connect from a .NET app to a DB2 server

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+db2+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004) for an explanation of why direct connection to database from mobile is discouraged.